# ListView - when some view onClickListener goes on - not listen to the rest onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, onitemclick

I have a `ListView` where I have a clickable `ImageView` for which I set `OnClickListener` in the `Adapter` class. I also have an `onItemClick` in `Activity` class.

So, as I supposed - `onClick` to `ImageView` should work first place, and `onItemClick` should work only if `ImageView` was not clicked. In reality when I tap Image - sometime `onClick` is working, sometimes `onItemClick` is working.

How can I separate these 2 areas easily? I know I can do 2 areas with `onClick`s for both in `Adapter`, but I wish to have `onItemClick` for the rest of the item except for the `ImageView`

```
      @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // используем созданные, но не используемые view
            View view = convertView;

                if (view == null) { 
                    switch(getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case 1: view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.first_position_list_main, parent, false);break;
                   case 2: view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.last_position_list_main, parent, false);break;
                    default: view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);break;
                  }

              imgstatus=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
              imgstatus.setTag(position);
            }
...
imgstatus.setOnClickListener(this);


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        listener.imageClick((Integer) view.getTag()); 
    }
```

item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ivAllother"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/play_fill_free_download" />
    <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/spare_play"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/spare_play" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImage"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.05"

        android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
        android:text="Молитвы Утренние"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDescr"
        android:text="12 МБ"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
<ImageView 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_stretch"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you post your rows layout?

Comment: just share your getView method in adaptor and onItemClick of listView

Comment: I edited post, didn't post whole getView() - it's huge

Comment: where is onItemClick ?